# GridView DropDownList control losing selected value after row deleted using AJAX call

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am deleting a row from a GridView using AJAX, and it works.

```
$('.btnDelete').click(function () {
            var rowsCount = <%=gvLineItems.Rows.Count %>;
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            if (rowsCount > 1) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "f_PromotionForm.aspx/DeleteItem",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ itemId: $(this).attr('id') }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.d) {
                            row.remove();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

f_PromotionForm.aspx/DeleteItem is a WebMethod that removes the item from the database.

Here is the GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvLineItems" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowDataBound="gvLineItems_RowDataBound" >
 <Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Description">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="dlItemDescription" runat="server" DataValueField="ItemCode" DataTextField="ItemDesc" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="-- SELECT ITEM --" Value="-1" />
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <input class="btnDelete" type="button" value="Delete" id='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Problem:**

On the subsequent postback (from clicking the Submit button, for example) after deleting a row, the first row after the position of the deleted row loses its selected value from a dropdownlist (it has the default value of -1).

When I check POST in my browser, the dropdownlist's selected value for that row is being sent.  The rest of the dropdownlists in other rows are not losing their selected value.  It is only the dropdownlist in that first row after the deleted one.  Also, other fields in that row with the problem are still retaining their values (I didn't show these fields in my Gridview code above in order to keep things simple).

On postback triggered by a button with an event handler, the following sequence of events occur leading up to the problem:

**Page_Init:** Gridview items are loaded from the database and databound

```
 //call to db and fill datatable dt with query results (dt has correct rows & values), then:
 gvLineItems.DataSource = dt;
 gvLineItems.DataBind();
```

**Page_Load:** nothing that impacts the Gridview happens here

**Event Handler:**

```
protected void btnSave_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveForm();
}

private bool SaveForm() {
    foreach(GridViewRow row in gvLineItems.Rows)  //this has the correct number of rows
    {
        DropDownList dlItemDescription = (DropDownList) row.FindControl("dlItemDescription");

        //test2 correctly shows the selected item value
        //except for the first row after the previously deleted row.

        var test2 = dlItemDescription.SelectedItem.Value; //**PROBLEM

        //save stuff...
    }
}
```

**Please note:**
A constraint is that the GridView can not use ViewState, so I have it disabled.

## **Question:**

How do I prevent the dropdownlist from losing its selected value?

Comment: can you use viewstate on the dropdown only?

Comment: @wazz - no.  when many rows are added to the table, viewstate becomes the State Puff Marshmellow Man and causes performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

i've used [this approach](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=256) before to help with post-ajax stuff on the page. very useful. you'll still have to figure out how to save the value of the problem-dropdown and reapply the value. you could save the value, pre-POST, to a hidden field on the page, the reapply it, end-POST. hth.

Comment: using a hidden field may do the trick.  i'm about to leave for the day, so i will give this a shot tomorrow.

Comment: this didn't work.  i added a hidden field, and verified it is updated before postback.  html rendering shows the hidden fields and table structure correctly, and POST is correct, but the hidden field for that row after the deleted one doesn't have a value, even in Request.Form.